# Add Multiple Items in Cart with Unique Title

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing Shopping Cart App in which i need to allow user to add multiple item(s) in Cart, like we see in other shopping cart apps.

Here, i have written a code to add item in cart, but not able to allow user to add Multiple Items in Cart.

And I also don't want to show duplicate Item(s) in List

**Constants.java:-**

```
public class Constants {
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sItem_Detail = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}
```

**LazyAdapter.java:-**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    String itemTitle, itemCost;
    TextView title, cost;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_items, null);

        title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); 
        cost = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.cost); 
        ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(item.get(ItemsActivity.KEY_TITLE));
        cost.setText(item.get(ItemsActivity.KEY_COST));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(item.get(com.example.sample.ItemsActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);

        //Button mImgAddCart
        Button mImgAddCart = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_to_order);
        mImgAddCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    itemTitle = title.getText().toString();
                    itemCost = cost.getText().toString();   

                    if (Constants.sItem_Detail.size() <= 0) {
                        HashMap<String, String> sTempObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        sTempObj.put(ItemsActivity.KEY_TITLE, itemTitle);
                        sTempObj.put(ItemsActivity.KEY_COST, itemCost);
                        Constants.sItem_Detail.add(sTempObj);
                    }

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            activity);
                    alertdialog.setTitle(activity.getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.app_name));
                    alertdialog.setMessage("Item Added to Cart");

                    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) 
                                {
                                    activity.finish();
                                }
                            });     
                    alertdialog.show();         
                }
            });

        return vi;
    }
}
```

**Please show me the code, which i need to write to do achieve this ...**

**Note:** *Still i am getting only single Item in a List*

Comment: Constants.sItem_Detail make collection as a global collection ,

Comment: can u post the output u r getting now?

Comment: to avoid duplicates you should use Set instead of List